# Пересечения диапазонов

Tags: python, массивы

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Python по уму сделать нахождения пересекаются ли диапазоны. Например, человек ищет людей в возрасте "от 9 до 14" и "от 15 до 21", при этом сам указывает, что ему "от 18 до 21". Второй человек же указывает что ему "от 8 до 11" и ищет при этом "от 21 до 40". Необходимо, чтобы все были довольны. То есть, во-первых искомый человек должен соответствовать искомым промежуткам возраста, во-вторых если тот кто ищет не удовлетворяет параметрам поиска искомого - то поиск должен вернуть false.
Наглядно такие массивы:

```
"search_users"{
"user_1" => {
    "my_age_from" => "18",
    "my_age_to" => "21",
    "wish_user_ages" => {
        {"from"=>"9", "to"=>"14"},
        {"from"=>"15", "to"=>"21"}
    }
},
"user_2" => {
    "my_age_from" => "8",
    "my_age_to" => "11",
    "wish_user_ages" => {
        {"from"=>"21", "to"=>"40"}
    }
},

....
```

Как найти только пересекающихся пользователей. Чтобы они друг другу были угодны. Есть вариант циклом проходить все условия, но это слишком трудно и как-то трудно укладывается в голове, был бы ещё возраст свой не диапозоном - не было бы проблем. И мне кажется есть какой-нибудь вообще более простой метод нежели циклы с условиями. Пожалуйста, помогите, гуру!))

Comment: 1- ваш ввод похож на php array, что наиболее близко соответствует `OrderedDict` в Питоне (списки в Питоне не имеют именованных ключей, словари в Питоне не поддерживают порядок). Если Вы намеренно использовали метку python для вопроса, то преобразуйте входные данные в формат, понимаемый Питоном (например, в json текст). Метка [tag:массивы] скорее всего неуместна 2- Уточните в чём Ваш вопрос. Вы хотите хоть какой-нибудь алгоритм, который найдёт для всех пользователей список подходящих по возрасту пользователей? Или Вам нужен алгоритм с определённым Big O поведением?

Comment: 1 - это не должно быть не на что не похоже, я просто для наглядности дал массив, руками написал. Вопрос именно в алгоритме на python, Как найти пользователя который тебе подходит и более того чтобы ты этому пользователю тоже подходил. На у мне только пришло 2 цикла, сначала проверка по всем диапозонам желаний пользователя который ищет, а потом если такой пользователь попался цикл уже на его желаниях для пользователя который ищет. Но это всё мне кажется не самым рациональным решением, может рекурсивную функцию какую-то можно сделать. Также туплю и не могу условие написать соответствует ли

Comment: один диапазон другому. было бы что нибудь такое range(8,14) is in range(14,18) - true. Было бы удобно)

Comment: 1- слово "массив" означает не то что вы думаете (посмотрите, например, описание метки). 2- Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, отредактируйте Ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну раз начали минусовать и править всякие формальности типа почему ты использовал слово "массив". Написал алгоритм сам, и надеюсь кто-то найдётся, кто сможет его улучшить :)

```
def isComplyUsers(user1, user2, exchange=true):
for wish_age in user1.wish_user_ages:
    # user2 не удовлетворяет желаниям user1
    if(user2.my_age_from > wish_age.to or (user2.my_age_from < wish_age.from and user2.my_age_to < wish_age.to)):
        continue
    else:
        if exchange:
            # Меняем местами и чтобы всё это не зациклилось говорим, что местами менять больше не требуется
            return isComplyUsers(user2, user1, false)
        else:
            return true
        break;

return false
```